# Parallel resonant induction heater

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, resonance, induction, reactive-power

I implemented a parallel LC induction heater using theory. I made a simple square wave Inverter providing a frequency of 20kHz to the tuned LC circuit. The problem I'm facing is that my tank is not drawing any current although the tank is at resonance with the supply. 
The picture of the output wave across the coil wrt ground is attached. Should I attach a resistance in parallel to the tank? I don't have any resistance in parallel to that. 
The picture of the circuit is also attached. [image: Circuit of the parallel tank]

[image: Voltage waveform on the tank circuit. It is at 20kHz, the oscilloscope was fluctuating because of switching harmonics.]

EDIT:

@Marla - I have a variable dc power supply with a built-in ammeter and voltmeter. It has a max rating of 30V at 15A. So, that's where I'm measuring the current. The scope is stating the wrong frequency due to switching harmonics (stays constant at 20.2kHz then fluctuates then goes back to 20.2kHz). The switching frequency of Mosfets is 20.2kHz.
Component values => L=1.9uH ; C=33uF; fsw=20.2kHz.

Comment: Component values?  Also your scope says 10 kHz. How do you measure current? You said tank isn't drawing current. Edit this into you question.

Comment: Also, what load do you have in coil? Photographs will help.

Comment: @Marla - the load was the tip of cast iron pliers. The inner dia of the coil is around 2.5inches and its an 8SWG copper wire wound into a 7 turn coil to give 1.9uH inductance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that both the left side of coil and right side of coil are being switched?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it wouldn't go in negative polarity.

Comment: Well it sounds as if your tank circuit is not connected. If waveform is indeed the voltage across the coil, then current must be flowing in coil.  ** Also, when you get the circuit running, remember what I said in your previous question  about parallel tank circuit not liking being driven by a voltage source.

Comment: @Marla - The tank is connected and I added two inductors, one on each side of the tank. The circuit is complete, however, the large amounts of current that should be drawn, when a workload is inserted, do not. Is there any chance that as the tank impedance at resonance is infinite, there is very minimal current and I'll have to add a resistance in parallel, to ensure that the current goes to the tank?

Comment: In fact, it should draw very little current in a parallel resonance circuit at resonant frequency.. [see this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/117598/178941). If you need to drive a high current through the inductor, you should consider a series resonance.

Comment: @Pojj - but how does a parallel resonant induction heater work then?

Comment: Parallel tank circuit is used in many induction heaters. Have you tried adjusting your oscillator frequency to get very close to resonance? Putting a work piece (load) in the coil lowers the impedance of the tank circuit.

Comment: @Marla - the impedance does not significantly decrease. If the inductance without any load is 1.9u then with the load its just 1.92u or 1.93u.

Comment: Btw I removed the chokes and now the current in the circuit is 2.1A at 12V without any load. It does not change when I put the load inside.

Comment: However, I do hear a frequency ringing sound when I insert the load. Otherwise I don't hear any sound. So, I'm pretty sure something is happening, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: So, a miracle occurs and you are now drawing current. Re-read what I stated. The impedance of the tank circuit decreases (not the coil). I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @Marla - sorry. My bad. Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

For parallel resonant heating circuits, you need to include a matching inductor in the inverter output in series with the parallel LC tank, something like as shown in the following image:

[image: Parallel resonant induction heater with matching inductors]

Image source: https://www.uihm.com/en/Induction-Heating-Technology/Base-details-of-High-Frequency-Induction-Heating.html

Having an inductor on only one side is in fact sufficient. The matching inductor helps pushing energy into the parallel resonant circuit against the rejecting voltages present across the LC tank making it a current source inverter.

That being said, too much inductance would also prevent current flow to the LC tank and cause power to be reduced. Try with few turns without any magnetic core at safe low voltage and increase further to arrive at an optimal value as per need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add a citation or link for the image you copied into your answer. Our site policy is that all material copied into an answer must have proper attribution.